# Goal is to pull the video driver version from the display information, then compare it to a list of versions supported

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, awk, filestream

The text file has following information:

```
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 5/22/2014, 14:20:52
       Machine name: CONFERENCE13
   Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pac
k 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Mario, Inc.
       System Model: Mario Virtual Platform
               BIOS: PhoenixBIOS 4.0 Release 6.0     
          Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
             Memory: 2048MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 2048MB RAM
          Page File: 1302MB used, 2792MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode
------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: Mario SVGA 3D
       Manufacturer: Mario, Inc.
          Chip type: Mario Virtual SVGA 3D Graphics Adapter
           DAC type: n/a
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_15AD&DEV_0405&SUBSYS_040515AD&REV_00
     Display Memory: 223 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 35 MB
      Shared Memory: 188 MB
       Current Mode: 1555 x 794 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic Non-PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: unknown
         Monitor Id: 
        Native Mode: unknown
        Output Type: HD15
        Driver Name: vm3dum64.dll,vm3dum,vm3dgl64.dll,vm3dgl
Driver File Version: 7.14.0001.2032 (English)
     Driver Version: 7.14.1.2032
        DDI Version: unknown
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.0
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 2/11/2014 03:15:04, 258264 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: n/aWHQL Date Stamp: n/a
  Device Identifier: {D7B71B4D-4745-11CF-ED71-0424A1C2CA35}
          Vendor ID: 0x15AD
          Device ID: 0x0405
          SubSys ID: 0x040515AD
        Revision ID: 0x0000
 Driver Strong Name: oem13.inf:VMware.NTamd64.6.0:VM3D_AMD64:7.14.1.2032:pci\ven_15ad&dev_0405&subsys_040515ad&rev_00
     Rank Of Driver: 00F60000
        Video Accel: 
      Deinterlace Caps: n/a
       D3D9 Overlay: n/a
            DXVA-HD: n/a
       DDraw Status: Not Available
         D3D Status: Not Available
         AGP Status: Not Available

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Speakers (Mario Virtual Audio (DevTap))
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: PNPB009
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: vmwvaudio.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0000.3800 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: n/a
          Date and Size: 11/13/2013 21:22:16, 46672 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: VMware
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0x0
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 0, 0
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 0, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No**
```

I am trying to pull card name and driver file version from the display devices and then compare with certain list as follow:

```
Windows XP  Windows Vista   Windows 7   Windows 8   Windows 8.1 Windows Server 2008 R2
View 3.1.3 build 252693 
VMware SVGA II
Version: 11.6.0.35
Dated: 4/21/2010
VMware SVGA 3D
Version: 17.14.1.42
Dated: 4/21/2010
Not Supported   Not Supported   Not Supported   Not Supported
View 4.0.2 build 294291 
VMware SVGA II
Version: 11.6.0.35
Dated: 4/21/2010
```

Tried awk but is giving me some error, new to awk and bash need some help thank you.

```
awk 'BEGIN{
 FS="="; OFS=" - "; DispalyDevices=""
}
function display(){
 print displaydevices,cardname,driverfileversion
}
/DisplayDevices/{
   if(cardname!="") display(); 
   cardname=""; driverfileversion=""; display=$0; 
   gsub("Display.*PLAY"; "Display",display)
}
/cardname/{cardname=$2}
/driverfileversion/{driverfileversion=$2}
END{display}' dx_diag.txt | cat > dx_outputfile.txt
```

`**

The error is:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
```

Within this context:

```
    BEGIN{FS="="; OFS=" - "; DispalyDevices=""}function display(){print displaydevices,cardname,driverfileversion}/DisplayDevices/{if(cardname!="") display(); cardname=""; driverfileversion=""; display=$0; >>>  gsub("Display.*PLAY"; <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1**
```

Comment: Displaying the whole script on one line like that makes it impossible to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  gsub("Display.*PLAY"; "Display",display)
```

to

```
  gsub("Display.*PLAY", "Display",display)
  #-------------------^--- comma, not semi-colon
```

IHTH